# Broadcast error when adding ndarray and sparse matrix converted to dense in python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I am converting from a scipy sparse matrix to a dense matrix and adding that to an ndarray using a += operator and I am getting a broadcast error. The ndarray has a shape (M,) while the dense matrix has a shape (M,1). When I try and convert the numpy.matrix to an ndarray the shape becomes (1,M). I also tried using reshape(M,) after the conversion and the shape becomes (M,M). Could someone please explain where am I messing up.

```
M = 100
N = 1000
K = 4
a= np.zeros((M,K))

b = sp.csr_matrix(np.ones((N,1)))
d = sp.csr_matrix(np.ones((M,N)))

c = np.ones(())
for k in range(K): 
    a[:,k] += d.dot(b).todense()
```

P.S: I am a newbie to both python and stackoverflow. Apologies if this is a wrongly framed question or if this question was already asked earlier (I couldn't find it)

Comment: Could you post a short, self-contained example we could try out that gives the broadcast error?

Comment: @agf In the example above, I get the following error:Non-broadcastable operand with shape (100) doesn't match the broadcast shape (100,100)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Side note to future googlers, OP's code has the following package imported:

```
> import numpy as np
> import scipy.sparse as sp
```

Anyway, let's begin with our explanation.

---

You can check your matrix size using:

```
> np.shape(your_matrix_here) #equals to MATLAB: > size(your_matrix_here)
```

As you call todense(), you got:

```
matrix([[ 1000.],  #shape: (1, 100)
        [ 1000.],
        [ 1000.],
        ...
```

while a[:,1] looks like this:

```
array([ 0.,  0., ... ,  0.,  0.]) #shape: (100,)
```

So you may want to transpose your matrix using transpose().

---

But transposing the matrix returns matrix containing matrix:

```
matrix([[ 1000.,  1000., ... , 1000.,  1000.]]) #shape: (1, 100)
```

and for some reason `d.dot(b).todense().transpose()[0]` doesn't return the first element the matrix:

```
matrix([[ 1000.,  1000., ... , 1000.,  1000.]]) #still the same!
```

---

This can be fixed using:

```
> np.array(d.dot(b).todense().transpose())[0]
```

thus returning:

```
array([ 1000.,  1000., ... 1000.,  1000.])
```

---

Now two of them got the same shape, allowing them to perform matrix operation:

```
> np.shape(np.array(d.dot(b).todense().transpose())[0]) #(100,)

> np.shape(a[:,1])                                      #(100,)
```

---

**In conclusion,** you want to change this line:

```
a[:,k] += d.dot(b).todense()
```

to:

```
a[:,k] += np.array(d.dot(b).todense().transpose())[0]
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried np.array(d.dot(b).todense()).reshape(M,) and I'm wondering why it did not work.